# How to read data from xml file in python using minidom

Tags: python, xml, minidom

What is the best (re: easiest) way to read a value from an xml file using python? I'm a novice, and have tried to play around with minidom, but am not sure of how to format the script.

The XML in /tmp/text.xml:

```
<computer>
<location>
<username>FirsLast</username>
</location>
</computer>
```

I want to parse the username and use it as a variable.

Here's what I've tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import xml.dom.minidom as minidom

doc = minidom.parse('/tmp/text.xml')
location = doc.getElementsByTagName('location')[0]
username = location.getAttribute('username')

print(username)
```

I don't get any results at all. I'd expect to see `FirsLast`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the top of my head:

```py
import xml.dom.minidom as minidom
doc = minidom.parse('/tmp/tes.xml')
location = doc.getElementsByTagName('location')[0]
# If I recall carriage return and spaces are text nodes so we
# need to skip those
username = list(filter(lambda x: x.nodeType == minidom.Node.ELEMENT_NODE, location.childNodes))
print(username[0].firstChild.nodeValue)
```

You're assuming that `username` is an attribute of `location` and it's not. It's a child node and it contains another child note which is the text. Minidom is quite cumbersome, so unless you **really** have to work with it (security reasons comes to mind) I'll advice you to use `xml.etree.ElementTree`

**UPDATE**

Op requested an example using ET:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
sample = """
<computer>
<location>
<username>FirsLast</username>
</location>
</computer>
"""
doc = ET.fromstring(sample)
username = doc.findall('./location/username')
print(username[0].text)
```

Comment: I'm up for xml.etree.ElementTree. How do I parse the username though? I managed to get the 'location' by using "for child in root:
 print(child.tag, child.attrib)" but am unsure how to drill further down to get the 'username'

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much!

Comment: `ET` has the advantage of allowing you to use XPath, glad it helped.

Comment: related question - Can I then use that value as a variable later in a script?  If i add a line 's_username = (username[0].text)'

Comment: Of course, is just a `str`, nothing special bout it